# Property 'registerUser' does not exist on type 'typeof UserController'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I exported two functions (registerUser and loginUser) as default in my controller, it didn't throw any error at the controller file but when I try getting the routes it throws this error - Property 'registerUser' does not exist on type 'typeof UserController'

My userRoutes Code is as shown below:

userRoutes.ts

[here is an image of my userRoutes code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRkaH.png)

I wanted to export two functions as default, so I used class constructor

My userController code is as shown below:

userController.ts

[here is an image of userController code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOK0S.png)

Comment: Instead of sharing the codes as screenshots, sharing them using the code formatting tool allows you to write a more readable question.

Comment: I'll do that next time , I found it a bit difficult as I'm not yet perfect in using stackoverflow, thanks for the advise

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, I didn't construct the class in my userRoute file.

wrong - `const { registerUser, loginUser } = userController`

Correct - `const { registerUser, loginUser } = new userController()`